# Meaning of "The database X needs to be upgraded" in ClearTrace

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler, sql-server-tools

I'm trying out ClearTrace from http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/download.html , but it isn't very user friendly from my first impression.  I have a database in SQL Server 2008 that I'm adding in the ClearTrace - Options dialogue, but it says "The database mydatabase needs to be upgraded.  Would you like to upgrade it?".  If I click No, I can't continue.  What does it mean to upgrade the database in this context?  The support forums don't seem to answer this.

Comment: Flagging as off topic since it's particular to a piece of software.

Comment: @JohnM it's a dba tool though?  According to http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/1128/8146 tools are "officially on-topic"?

Comment: There is [this](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/is-dba-the-best-place-for-questions-related-to-sql-dba-tools) DBA.SE meta question, but to me it's a tool I've never heard of and an issue specific to it's install process, not actually a problem to do with DBA work.

Comment: It is a commonly known tool in the SQL Server community, as well as the individual that wrote it. I would categorize this along with questions about `sp_WhoIsActive` or Ola's scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that the Options dialogue is for the database that ClearTrace uses to store its own application data.  It created a dedicated database for it and it added its own tables to that database, during the 'upgrade'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database you created via Options and Tools it could be the database is not at a compatibility version that ClearTrace needs.

I would suggest letting it create a new database, as doing this I generally never experience issues.